# Bottom placeholder in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, footer, sharepoint-online, sticky-footer, spfx

I created a footer component in SharePoint Online using SPFX. The footer is automatically created fixed because of the bottom placeholder, but I need it to be located at the bottom of the page( sticky). 
I need a custom SPFX solution with dynamically links for the footer. 
Is there any workaround for that?

Thank you!